# Diaplay confirmation message box and fire click event

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.NET, when the user clicks a button, I want to display a confirmation message box, which the following code does:

button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('This will perform the task. Are you sure?');");

When the user clicks OK on the confirmation message box, I want to fire a click event. How do I do that? The click event method is attached to the button's Click event but the method doesn't fire. Thanks.

Comment: Does it need to be an onclick event? Why not just set up an If statement that if the message box returns true (clicking confirm not cancel) then it calls a subroutine to do whatever you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps you should use `jQuery`, it's very simple to do what you want.

```
 $('#buttonId').click(function (e){
    //do whatever you want
 })
```

Comment: A running joke about the overuse of jQuery.  I am a huge fan of jQuery, but there are certain tasks( like adding numbers or recreating javascript's built in `confirm` behavior) that do not justify adding an entire javascript library like jQuery (IMHO).

Comment: ohhhh!!! sorry i didn't thought it like that! Abe Miessler is 100% right about that. I just love to work with jQuery when managing javascript, i feel it's way more simple.

Answer (score 2):

Try defining your button like so:

```
<asp:Button id="btn_Submit" runat="Server" 
            OnClientClick="return confirm('This will perform the task. Are you sure?')"
            OnClick="btn_Submit_Click" />
```

Comment: I did exactly that, but no luck. I also tried with both true and false values for UseSubmitBehavior but it still won't work.